# ruby and Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new font size

Tags: ruby, gtk3

I am using ruby 2.6.3, installed by compiling the source.
When using Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new, the default font size given is 10.
Is it possible to call Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new with a different size, such
as 24, so that I can avoid having to change the size each time I select a font.
Here is how I am doing things:

```
dialog = Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new(:title => "Select font",
                                          :parent => self,                                         
                                          :action =>  Gtk::FileChooserAction::OPEN,
                                      :buttons => [[Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT], [Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::ResponseType::CANCEL]])
```

I have tried (in the argument list) :size => 24, :default_size => 24, etc. This does not work. I'm just guessing here. I have searched a lot, with no luck. I also looked in the gem sample dirs at test-gtk-font-chooser-dialog.rb and other files but no luck.

I am using Linux Mint Mate 19.1, installed a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the size through a [Pango.FontDescription](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-pangofontdescription.html#constructor-pangofontdescription). A short example in Python would be:

```
font_chooser = Gtk.FontChooserDialog.new(title = "Select font", parent = self)
font_description = Pango.FontDescription.new()
font_description.set_size(24 * Pango.SCALE)
font_chooser.set_font_desc(font_description)
```

**EDIT**
And here is a complete example in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

'''
ZetCode Ruby GTK tutorial

This program runs a font dialog with a default (settable) font size.

Author: Jan Bodnar
Website: www.zetcode.com
Last modified: May 2014
'''

require 'gtk3'
require 'pango'

class RubyApp < Gtk::Window

    def initialize
        super
        init_ui
    end

    def init_ui

        set_title "Center"
        signal_connect "destroy" do 
            Gtk.main_quit 
        end

        button = Gtk::Button.new
        button.set_label "Font"    
        button.signal_connect "clicked" do 
            dialog = Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new(:title => "Select font", :parent => self, :action =>  Gtk::FileChooserAction::OPEN, :buttons => [[Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT], [Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::ResponseType::CANCEL]])
            font_description = Pango::FontDescription.new
            font_description.set_size 24 * Pango::SCALE
            dialog.set_font_desc font_description
            dialog.run
        end

        add button
        set_default_size 300, 200
        set_window_position Gtk::WindowPosition::CENTER
        show_all
    end   
end


window = RubyApp.new
Gtk.main
```

Comment: This works for returning the font size of 24, but what I want is for the
default font presented for the selection in the dialogue window to
automatically be something like "24", or "30", etc. My dialogue window
gives me a default choice of "10", which of course can be changed before
clicking the select button (by using the slider, or by typing, etc). I
know this can be done, because my default text editor, "xed" gives a
different size choice by default. Of course it is not written in ruby.

Comment: Thats exactly what this does. If it doesn't work for you, would you mind updating your question with a MCVE?

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. This works like I wanted it to. Here is my finished method:

Comment: dialog = Gtk::FontChooserDialog.new(:title => "Select font",
                                          :parent => self,
                                          :action =>  Gtk::FileChooserAction::OPEN,
                                          :buttons => [[Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT], [Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::ResponseType::CANCEL]])

      dialog.set_size_request(1200, 960)
      font_desc = Pango::FontDescription.new
      font_desc.set_size 24 * Pango::SCALE
      dialog.set_font_desc font_desc
      #dialog.run

      end

    end